# The answers are not ordered anymore based on the number of votes?

Tags: support

Until a couple of days ago, the answers to questions would always be ordered based on the number of votes they received and the answer that was accepted. However, recently this has changed for my browser, see for example:

[image]

Am I the only one who if suffering from this (assuming this is a bug)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you selected the tab *votes* on the right, just above the answers?

> [image]